# Interactive home screen icons

Tags: android, interactive, android-icons

I searched this topic and couldn't find anything on it.
Is there a way to make interactive icons on the home screen?
for example there is "clean master" that after you click an icon of it, it make an animation. Also there is this facebook thing where you get a message and an icon with the profile picture of the one that messaged you pops up.

I can't figure out or find a way to implement this kind of stuff..

I would be happy if any one could give me some kind of direction..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: Wow! it what i was searching for! Thank You! Do you have any more information on that topic or guides or tutorials or keywords that i can use to search for it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example there is "clean master" that after you click an icon of it,
>   it make an animation.

**The icon doesn't animate.** When you click on it, a new transparent Activity opens which the icon at the same position where the original icon is. The animations happens entirely on the activity.

The activity is transparent so you get a feel that the icon itself is animating. If you notice carefully, **you can find the navigation bar coming up** if you tap somewhere while its animating.

> Also there is this facebook thing where you get a message and an icon
>   with the profile picture of the one that messaged you pops up.

[image]

**It is know as Chat Heads.** You ca create your own, but it  an take some time and is a bit involving. If you are a beginner and/or you are in a hurry, you can use [this](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView) library. I have used it and **it works perfectly**.

Comment: @user3478552 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer if you want activity on the home screen is to implement a widget.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

Comment: @karaokyo gave the answer I searched for.. I don't think widgets will do the work.. i am searching for a more interactive thing. Like the chathead of facebook. It should be able to appear in any activity on top of it.. If you can give any additional information on this topic. It will be helpful!